# Add simultaneity two object depend on each other

Tags: linq

I am newbie in linq.
I am building a web api project with net core.
This is what i am trying to deal with:
I had two tables: "1" as document and "2" as caisse.

[image]

In the same query, I want to add table 1 and table 2.
The problem is that I do not know the id of the table 2. the id is Auto-increment.
I had the idea to get the Max id but i think this is a not appropriate solution.
how can i solve this problem ?

```
[HttpPost("addDocument")]
  public IActionResult AddShoppingCart([FromBody]DocumentDto document)
{
if (Document== null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            try
            {
                Caisse caisse = new Caisse();
                 caisse.dateDocumentRelease=Date.now();
                 caisse.dateOfAmount=Date.now();
                _iCaisseService.AddCaisse(caisse)
              // here i don't konw the id of the caisse after adding it 
               _iDocumentService.AddDocument(document);

                if (!_iDocumentService.Save())
                {
                    return StatusCode(500, "A problem happened while handling your request.");
                }
                return StatusCode(200, "good");            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, "A problem happened while handling your request.");
            }
}
```

Comment: Please show some small example of data and ideally some code.

Comment: I add a small example of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Document AddCaisse(Caisse caisse)
        {
            return _context.Caisse .Add(caisse).Entity;
        }
```

this linq query solve the problem.
At the post method, i call the addCaisse.

```
var object= _iDocumentService.addCaisse(caisse);
return Ok(object.Id);
```